# Is there a better way to select multiple rows in a table using .eq()?

Tags: jquery, css

I’m trying to apply css styles for the specific rows (row #3 and  #6) in the table through Jquery and below is what I currently doing. It works perfect but I’m wondering whether there is a better way of doing it instead of declaring separate variables to hold individual rows.

```
var row = $('.table tr').eq(3);
var row1 = $('.table tr').eq(6);

var rowstyles = {
    height: "24px",
    background: "#444",
    fontStyle: "italic"
};

row.css(rowstyles);
row1.css(rowstyles);
```

In the above code I’ve declared `var row` and `var row1` to reference respective rows, instead can one variable reference both the rows that I want to apply the styles to?

Comment: I found this works too but not sure when you take performance into consideration when comparing to other options. var rows = $('.table tr:eq(3), .table tr:eq(6)');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var rows = $(".table").find("tr:eq(3), tr:eq(6)");

Comment: Please provide an explanation with code snippets. Related documentation: [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var rowstyles = {
    height: "24px",
    background: "#444",
    fontStyle: "italic"
};

var rows = [3, 6];

$.each(rows, function(){
    $('.table tr').eq($(this)).css(rowstyles);
}
```

Comment: This will work too but I go with Tim B's answer because it's one-liner.

Comment: I agree. But I have only two rows in this case, will go this route when I need to extend it for multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/pKn3P/)

You can give a class to tr 3 and tr 6 -
 Then use as follows

```
var rows = $('table tr.myclass');

var rowstyles = {
    height: "24px",
    background: "#444",
    fontStyle: "italic"
};

rows.css(rowstyles);
```

Comment: Not very useful when you can't alter the HTML of the document.

Comment: As Terry says I can't alter the HTML in this case.